# Router 6 - calling child component function from the parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

App.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <MainHeader />, 
    children:[
      { index: true, element: <Home />, loader :loaderHome }, 
    ]
  }
])

const App = () => { 
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />; 
}

export default App;
```

MainHeader.js

```
import { Outlet, NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainHeader = (props) => { 
  const testRef = useRef();
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <>
      <header className={styles['main-header']}>
        <NavLink to={location.pathname==='/' ? testRef.current.testHandler : '/event'}>
          Home3
        </NavLink>
        <Login />
      </header>
      <Outlet innerRef={testRef} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MainHeader;
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

const Home = React.forwardRef((props, ref) =>
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      testHandler: testHandler
    }
  })

  // I had to useCallback to prevent this function from reloading when the useEffect loads
  const testHandler=async(e)=>{
    console.log('enter test handler')
  }

  return (
    ............
  );
})

export default Home;
```

What I want - in `MainHeader.js`, `NavLink` when clicked, if the route is `'/'` then call function `testHandler` defined in `Home.js` (child) otherwise go to route `'/event'`.

I tried doing this using `forwardRef` as with function components, this is what I have thus far but it isn't working. I tried passing a ref in the `Outlet` component in `MainHeader.js` to `Home.js` to call the `testHandler` function.

Any ideas? Do I have to modify `App.js`? Is there any other way to call the `testHandler` function from `MainHeader.js`?

This worked, thanks for your help:

**App.js**

```
const App=()=>{ 
  const mainHeaderToHomeRef=useRef();

  const router=createBrowserRouter([{
    path:'/',
    element: <MainHeader ref={mainHeaderToHomeRef} />, // wraps around all the child routes below
    children:[
      {index:true, element:<Home ref={mainHeaderToHomeRef} />, loader:loaderHome }, // index route ./
    ]
  }])

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />; 
}

export default App;
```

**MainHeader.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet, NavLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainHeader=React.forwardRef((props, ref)=>{ 
    const location = useLocation();

    const homeHandleClick=(e)=>{
        if(location.pathname==='/' && ref.current){
            e.preventDefault() // stop the link from navigating
            ref.current.homeHandler() // call func in Home.js
        }
    }

    return(
        <>
        <header className={styles['main-header']}>
            <h1>Rotten Tomatoes</h1>
            <NavLink to='/' onClick={homeHandleClick}>Home3</NavLink>
            <Login/>
        </header>
        {/* Outlet is the place where the child routes should be rendered to, i.e. all the 
        children components in App.js */}
        <Outlet/>
        </>
    );
})

export default MainHeader;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

const Home = React.forwardRef((props, ref) =>

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return{homeHandler:homeHandler}
  })
  
  // I had to useCallback to prevent this function from reloading when the useEffect loads
  const homeHandler=useCallback(async(e)=>{
        console.log('home handler entered')
    },[]);

  return (
    ............
  );
})

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're on the right track with using React.forwardRef() to pass a ref from the parent MainHeader component to the child Home component. However, there are a couple of issues with your current implementation.

Firstly, you're trying to access testHandler before it's defined in Home. You should define testHandler before you try to pass it through the ref. Additionally, since you're passing testHandler through a ref, you'll need to wrap it in useCallback() to ensure that the same function instance is used on every render.

Secondly, in MainHeader, you're trying to call testRef.current.testHandler directly, but testRef.current will be null until Home has mounted. You'll need to add a check to ensure that testRef.current is defined before trying to call testHandler.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

const MainHeader = (props, ref) => {
  const testRef = useRef();
  const location = useLocation();

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (testRef.current) {
      testRef.current.testHandler();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <header className={styles['main-header']}>
        <NavLink to={location.pathname === '/' ? '#' : '/event'} onClick={handleClick}>
          Home3
        </NavLink>
        <Login />
      </header>
      <Outlet innerRef={testRef} />
    </>
  );
};

export default React.forwardRef(MainHeader);
```

Home.js:

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useCallback } from 'react';

const Home = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const testHandler = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('enter test handler');
  }, []);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    testHandler,
  }));

  return <div>Home Component</div>;
});

export default Home;
```

Here, MainHeader takes a ref parameter and passes it to Outlet as innerRef. In handleClick(), we check if testRef.current is defined before calling testHandler() on it.

In Home, we define testHandler using useCallback(), and pass it through the ref using useImperativeHandle().

I hope this works for you.

Comment: testRef.current is returning undefined in the handleClick method. Do I have to make any modification to App.js? I'm getting warning: rning: forwardRef render functions accept exactly two parameters: props and ref. Did you forget to use the ref parameter?

Comment: I think something is wrong here: { index: true, element: <Home />, loader :loaderHome }... The innerRef from Outlet isn't reaching Home.js

Comment: @D.Rattansingh That is because the only prop [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) takes is a `context` React context value. Any forwarded ref would need to be passed directly to the `Home` component in `App`.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm realizing that is true, is there anyway to pass the forward ref directly in router 6?...... I'm also wondering now why they allow an innerRef property in outlet when it's not being forwarded to the child components

Comment: You can declare the React ref in `App` and pass down. Who is allowing an `innerRef` property in outlet? You can view the [source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L226-L237) and verify easily that `context` is the only accepted prop.

Comment: ok, I saw an example with someone using innerRef with Outlet and incorrectly assumed it was a prop... So you're saying to declare the ref in App.js and then forward pass it to both MainHeader.js and Home.js? How will that get the Navlink in MainHeader.js to call functio in Home.js?

Answer (score 1):

It's a huge React anti-pattern to call functions defined in other React components, typically indicative of a code smell.

Define `testHandler` higher in the ReactTree and pass down to the components where you are wanting to call it.

Also, `testHandler` isn't a valid `NavLink` `to` prop value, so you will have problems trying to do what you are trying to do anyway. Add an `onClick` handler to the `"/event"` link that conditionally cancels the navigation action and calls `testHandler`.

Example:

App.jsx

```
export default function App() {
  const testHandler = async (e) => {
    console.log("enter test handler");
  };

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <MainHeader {...{ testHandler }} />,
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <Home {...{ testHandler }} />,
          loader: loaderHome
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

MainHeader

```
const MainHeader = ({ testHandler }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <>
      <header className={styles["main-header"]}>
        <NavLink
          to="/event"
          onClick={(e) => {
            if (location.pathname === "/") {
              e.preventDefault();
              testHandler();
            }
          }}
        >
          Home3
        </NavLink>
        <Login />
      </header>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

Home

```
const Home = ({ testHandler }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>

      ...

      <button type="button" onClick={testHandler}>
        testHandler
      </button>

      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit router-6-calling-child-component-function-from-the-parent-component]

Comment: Thanks for your input. However I have some state in Home.js (that I'm trying to change) that should really be in Home.js and not App.js because no other child component in the routes will have anything to do with that state. I could have simply done this for the link: <NavLink to='/'>Home3</NavLink>, however if the user is already in the home page then the page will still be reloaded from the Database

Comment: I'm trying not to do this (for optimization purposes). Thus once I could click that NavLink in MainHead.js and access the testHandler function in child Home.js to print to console, then I could move on and clear the state thereby not needing a Database call

Comment: @D.Rattansingh I would still say this is a code smell, but if it's unavoidable then you can declare the ref in `App` and pass down/forward. I can create a sandbox fork and demo if you like. Can you clarify what the issue is that you are trying to solve by running a component function externally?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve optimization by accessing this function externally and learn how to navigate with router 6. Yes a sandbox example will be helpful

Comment: @Drew.Reese I got it working. I followed your directions, thanks. I'll update my question with the result

Comment: @D.Rattansingh Sorry I was busy and couldn't respond back earlier, but yes, you got it and understood the suggestion. Glad it is working now for you. Cheers.